# Getting NewLine character in FreeTextBox control in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using [FreeTextBox control](http://freetextbox.com/)

in asp.net.When I am getting its HtmlStrippedText in my code I am getting the String without HTML tags.Now how can I get the new line character from this String i.e. I want to Replace All the NewLine characters with Special Symbol "@".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Solution:

Got the HtmlStrippedText in String str and then got replace it like this:

```
char enter=(char)111;
temp= str.Replace(enter+"", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like the base ASP:TextBox, you can just grab the string  from the text property and do something like

```
 var test = txtYourControl.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "@");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will vary between browsers (perhaps even between the operating systems on which the browser is running). More on newline definitions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

I have found the most reliable option to be to search and replace "\n" rather than Environment.NewLine which is "\r\n" in a Windows environment.

```
string text = this.txtField.Text.Replace("\n", "@");
```

Comment: @AmandeepSingh - yes, I read your post and looked at the control. But you asked how to replace a newline character. A newline character is dependent on the user agent and/or the OS, not a web control, unless the web control is using its own custom delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlStrippedText is used to get the plain text
You should use the text property of freetextbox control

u can remove new line using this code.

```
lblTitle.Text = txtFreetextbox.Text.Replace("<br>","@");
```

Click this link
http://freetextbox.com/docs/ftb3/html/P_FreeTextBoxControls_FreeTextBox_Text.htm